# Combinar familias de columnas en Cassandra

Tags: base-de-datos, nosql, cassandra

Soy nuevo en Cassandra, estoy intentando realizar un ejercicio. El ejercicio esta compuesto por tres tablas:

**CURSOS**

```
 idc |                     titulo   | creditos | profesor
-----+------------------------------+----------+------------------
 105 |        Fonética y morfología |        5 | Miguel Hernández
 107 |          Lingüística General |        3 |     Samuel López
 108 |              Español Moderno |       10 |      Isabel Sanz
 104 | Literatura hispano-americana |        5 |   Paloma-Sánchez
 102 |               Griego Moderno |        7 |     Daniel Pérez
 106 |           Teorías literarias |        3 |      Juan García
 101 |           Filología románica |        7 |    Sara Martínez
 103 |           Literatura Moderna |       10 |    Amalia Sierra
```

**ESTUDIANTES**

```
ide  | estudiante
-----+-----------------
 201 |    Maria Mestre
 204 |   Carlo Berruzo
 203 |   Oriol Menezes
 207 |    Arianna Ruiz
 205 | Sofia Canyadell
 208 |   Naiara Zapico
 206 |    Marina Perez
 202 |   Rodrigo Calvo
```

**NOTAS**

```
 ide |        idc |     nota | fecha
-----+------------+----------+--------------
 201 |        101 |        B |    2019-02-11
 201 |        102 |        B |    2018-06-30 
 202 |        106 |        C |    2018-06-30
 203 |        103 |        A |    2019-02-11
 203 |        108 |        A |    2018-06-30
 204 |        105 |        B |    2020-01-04
 205 |        101 |        B |    2020-01-04
 205 |        103 |        B |    2020-01-04
```

Se pide:

- Recuperar la información de los cursos (titulo, créditos, nombre profesor, nombre estudiante) en los que un estudiante en particular ha atendido i ordenar por título del curso.
- Recuperar la información de los cursos en los que hubo estudiantes que recibieron una nota en concreto. Se pide título del curso, créditos, nombre profesor, identificador estudiante y ordenados por numero de créditos.

He creado las tablas y insertado los datos. Como ejemplo, se muestra debajo la tabla cursos creada:

```
CREATE TABLE mscfilologia.cursos (
    idc int,
    titulo text,
    creditos int,
    profesor text,
    PRIMARY KEY (idc)
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo combinar datos entre tablas para satisfacer los requerimientos del enunciado. Por ejemplo, la tabla cursos y estudiantes no sé como conectarlas. Quizás debería crear una tabla **cursos_by_estudiante** pero en ese caso de qué me sirve haber creado las tablas anteriores?

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas, la tabla Estudiantes y la tabla Notas tienen un campo ide que realmente es el mismo, es decir sabiendo que María Mestre tiene el código 201 puedes ver que ha obtenido 2 notas en la tabla Notas. Concretamente dos B. En esos 2 registros también existe el campo idc que hace referencia al campo idc de los Cursos.

Por tanto María Mestre ha sacado un B en Filología románica y otro B en Griego Moderno.

Para combinar las tablas en una instrucción SQL que devuelve todo lo anterior necesitas realizar dos JOIN por los campos comunes que tienen las tablas para poder relacionarlas y extraer el resto de información.

Intenta realizar la consulta SQL que te piden y ya te seguimos ayudando.

Comment: Pues no, su respuesta no es correcta,  cassandra es nosql, no admite join

Comment: Pues sí, no sabía que no se podían hacer joins. De todas formas e investigado un poco y se pueden hacer joins si usas SparkSQL ™ de Apache Spark y un conector ODBC y también hay varias opciones más como p.e. http://users.ics.forth.gr/~kondylak/publications/2016_EDBT.pdf

Comment: Bueno pues edita tu repuesta y aclara al usuario y a la comunidad en general el resultado de tu investigacion